# Scala: add prefix to each element in list

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I have a list of some partitions, like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and also I have main path, like:

```
"books/style/type="
```

I want to get a list of full path, like this:

[books/style/type=1/, books/style/type=2, books/style/type=3, books/style/type=4]

I understand I should use map method, something like this:

```
val full_path = partsList.map(x => base_path + x)
```

but I do not have enough experience and knowledge to bring it to the right form

full code:

```
val partsList = ConfigFactory.load().getStringList("part_list")

val base_path = ConfigFactory.load().getString("path")
  
  import spark.implicits._

val fullPathList = partsList.map(x => base_path+x)
```

in application conf:

part_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

path = "books/style/type="

Comment: Your code seems fine. Whats the problem?

Comment: Seems [to be doing](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1c7CcUpWRwe00j2Ozp1cTQ) what is requested.

Comment: I added screenshot with error, @Dima

Comment: You don't seem to have `partsList` defined in your screen shot anywhere. Also, do not post screenshots, post actual code. Check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some tips about how to write good questions on SO.

Comment: i tried to fix my question, @Dima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ConfigFactory` is from type safe config, `getStringList` returns a java list, not a scala collection, you need to convert it to scala:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val partsList = ConfigFactory.load().getStringList("part_list").asScala
...
```